# Unable to find traffic for specific device w/ Wireshark (over Wi-Fi)

Tags: networking, tcp, wifi, wireshark, wpa

I have a device communicating with a TCP server running on my machine. My machine is normally connected to the network via ethernet, however I also have a wireless adapter that I can use to connect to my router. The device (TCP client) is connected to my router (WPA2-Personal/ AES encryption/ security key).

I can see the device with Wireshark on my ethernet adapter communicating with my server. I cannot find the device when I look at the wireless adapter (I am looking for the device by IP). I went into Edit > Preferences > Protocols > IEEE 802.11 wireless Lan > Decryption Keys > and then set wpa=pwd "password:ssid" and wep-psk "key that I generated [here](https://www.wireshark.org/tools/wpa-psk.html)".

I have never used Wireshark to look at traffic that does not originate from my PC, however it's necessary in this particular instance to troubleshoot a problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What does this question have to do with programming? You should try to ask this question on [su].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(While I think of it, first: the root cause of this have no relationship whatsoever with encryption - otherwise you would see traffic, encrypted for sure, but you would still see "stuff" passing.)

**You will only see traffic to/from this device if it's multicast or broadcast.**

This is because the way communication occur in Wi-Fi/802.11 between AP (Access Point) and STA (Station). At the 802.11 level, every "unicast"[0] communication between let's say a STA A and a STA B actually do *not* go directly from STA A to STA B: there is first a 802.11 frame from STA A to the AP, and then the AP will send it to STA B etc.

So if your device send some multicast/broadcast traffic, you will see this - but only this (responses back to multicast/broadcast often being unicast).

Some traffic that you may see originating from this station will be for instance ARP requests - that's broascast, and as such it's the job of the AP to send this to all its STAs. You will see these.

Another very common example of such traffic in a Wi-Fi context is if the STA is a DHCP client. You will then see the DHCP request. In a typical scenario this STA will issue such a DHCP request just after association/authentication to the AP. In such case, from your PC running wireshark (which is another STA from the same AP), you will see the DHCP request, since it's broadcast and the AP will distribute it (I intentionally do not use the term "forward"). But usually not much more, because again in a typical scenario the AP is also the DHCP server, hence the rest of the communication regarding this DHCP process will occur directly between the AP and the said STA. You should also see, though, an ARP request - see above - issued by the said DHCP client STA, to check that the IP that it has just been offered by the DHCP server is indeed free, because that's what the DHCP protocol mandate[1] if correctly implemented.

Another not so common but not so rare either traffic that you may see are the one that are inherently broadcast:

- ICMPv6 neighbour solicitations/advertisement (from STA running a
  modern OS with dual IP stack)
- Dropbox LAN discovery protocol (and oh this can be quite noisy from
  regular PC STA)
- UPnP SSDP (that's UDP multicast on port 1900)
- ...and probably many more depending on the applications running in
  the STA (or AP of course, such as DHCP).

**This is a fundamental point to understand and never forget when working with Wi-Fi/802.11 in a AP/STA setup: all communication goes through the AP, *never* directly between STA[2][3].**

If you "have never used Wireshark to look at traffic that does not originate from my PC", you may not be familiar with the concept of [promiscuous mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Promiscuous_mode), but be warned that it is not the point and will not help here: promiscuous mode can only help in seeing traffic that arrive to your network interface but would normally be discarded by its driver or your OS stack. But here, the traffic actually never goes to your interface in the first place, because the AP will not send this traffic to it at the basic 802.11 level: **a fundamental role of an AP is to act like a bridge ("switch") between STAs, and you are in the same situation as you would be with a wired Ethernet switch, and you would need port mirroring on the switch to see such traffic**, because the switch is smart enough to not send this traffic to the port you would be connected to.

In the 802.11 context, aside from the **"regular mode"** and **"promiscuous mode"**, there's a third mode: [**"monitor"**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monitor_mode). In monitor mode - if everything goes OK, because that's not always obvious - your packet sniffing PC running `wireshark` will then not be a STA nor participate in any manner to any Wi-Fi traffic, but you may then "see everything" (encrypted if there's encryption, but `wireshark` can help).

About the tricky world of Wi-Fi packet sniffing, see:

[WLAN (IEEE 802.11) capture setup](https://wiki.wireshark.org/CaptureSetup/WLAN)

(though targeted to `wireshark`, the technical concepts apply also to other `pcap` based tools, such as `libpcap` (of course...) but also `tcpdump`)

[0]
I use the term "unicast" here at its root level, that is to say not in the "IP/layer 3" meaning of it (we're at the 802.11 level, which is PHY (layer 1) + Medium Access Control aka MAC (layer 2) - medium being "the air), but more fundamentally as "unicast = communication from a specific entity A to another specific entity B".

[1]:
From [RFC 2131, Dynamic Host Configuration Protocol](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2131.txt), 3.1 Client-server interaction - allocating a network address, page 16, paragraph 5:

> The client SHOULD perform a final check on the parameters (e.g., ARP
>   for allocated network address), and notes the duration of the lease
>   specified in the DHCPACK message.  At this point, the client is
>   configured.  If the client detects that the address is already in use
>   (e.g., through the use of ARP), the client MUST send a DHCPDECLINE
>   message to the server and restarts the configuration process.

[2]:
The (quite recent) [Wi-Fi direct](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct), which is not exclusive to AP/STA - but this would be another topic- changed the landscape in this regard.

[3]:
...and don't worry, this does not put any load to the AP software (ex this does not even go to the userland AP software such as for example `hostapd`), this is rather carefully managed by the ho-so-technically-sophisticated Wi-Fi hardware chipset.

**EDIT:**

Sorry, I've been too busy explaining the "why" of you questions, forgetting the "... now how to?":

> ...however it's necessary in this particular instance to troubleshoot
>   a problem.

So I've been using 2 approach:

**1/ Use monitor mode.**

Though, there can be many problems:

- your (sniffing) Wi-Fi hardware may not support it (usually not a
  problem on Linux at least, but...),
- your OS may not support and/or require specific hardware (see
  Wireshark's wiki link above, especially if you're on Windows),
- the radio environment may be annoyingly noisy (the case for me at
  work) and since you're sniffing PC is just passively listening on
  radio as opposed to connected to anything you may miss packets (also
  the case for me at work, that appear in `wireshark` "follow dialog" and
  then you see some "(XXX missing bytes)),
- and before that, you have the encryption problem and you may want to
  switch to non-encrypted to ease things, which may not be an option
  (I'm usually able to do that, but then too often some "(XXX missing
  bytes)" making the whole thing useless.

All in all, in my experience, I reserve monitor mode to low-level Wi-Fi chipset and basic 802.11 stack issues investigation = not for higher level applicative protocols troubleshooting. *But please, give it a try,* if that works for you that'd be fine.

**2/ Run the actual sniffing process on the device you're troubleshooting, and forward it to a dissecting station (a PC running `wireshark`/`tcpdump`).**

This require quite some control on the device (which is fine for me since since "I build them" so to speak). To put this to use I use an SSH connection to launch a `tcpdump` on the device - quite some prerequisites, so of course if you have no remote shell capabilities nor `pcap`/`tcpdump` executable on the device, that's useless to you... :-/ Yet I'd highly recommend it if do-able.

Here it goes:

```
ssh foo@device "/usr/sbin/tcpdump -U -s0 -w - -i <wireless interface on the device> 'not port 22'" | wireshark -k -i -
```

...this launches a `tcpdump` process on the device (of course the "foo" user must have proper privilege to launch `tcpdump` in its default promiscuous mode, though maybe its `--no-promiscuous-mode` option may be OK depending on your problem) sniffing on its own `<wireless interface on the device>`, filter out SSH itself so that the tool does not mix up with the traffic of interest, and send it back to the PC where it's in turn piped to `wireshark`. And "Voilà", watch the magic!

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for the great response! Although I'm still having some issues (on Windows), it looks like approach 1 is the way to go. You've definitely given me more than enough to try and work through it. Although I built the device I'm having the issues with, I'm sadly unable to run the capture on the device. The device is essentially just a small PIC microcontroller connected to a serial-to-WiFi adapter. I'm having issues connecting to other computers via TCP within the network (although it connects to our server via public IP without issues). Thank you again for the great response!